# How to create a simple Binding for previews

Tags: swiftui

With the new `@Binding` delegate and previews, I find it kinda awkward to always have to create a `@State static var` to create the neccesarry binding:

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    @Binding var someProperty: Double
    var body: some View {
        //...
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct TestView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    @State static var someProperty = 0.7
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView(someProperty: $someProperty)
    }
}
#endif
```

Is there a simpler way to create a binding, that proxies a simple values for testing and previewing?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use `.constant(VALUE)` in your Previews, no need to create a `@State`.

```
/// A value and a means to mutate it.
@propertyWrapper public struct Binding<Value> {

    /// Creates a binding with an immutable `value`.
    public static func constant(_ value: Value) -> Binding<Value>
}
```

e.g.

```
TestView(someProperty: .constant(5.0))
```

Comment: The given answer is correct; I don't want to imply otherwise. But I imagine the reason that the view being developed has a `@Binding` in the first place is because that view will mutate that data, and it would be nice to test that in a live preview. That's not possible with the given answer since the result of `.constant()` is an immutable binding. The way to let it change is given in the WWDC 2020 talk titled "Structure your app for SwiftUI previews" (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10149/), starting at the 16:43 mark.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote about this in depth [here](https://michaellong.medium.com/swiftui-binding-extensions-b6a9f27d2858?sk=1cd091e8e3dcdbffb1459e38aacd8ec7), but the short version is simply to add the following extension:

```swift
extension Binding {
    public static func variable(_ value: Value) -> Binding<Value> {
        var state = value
        return Binding<Value> {
            state
        } set: {
            state = $0
        }
    }
}
```

And then do...

```swift
struct TestView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView(someProperty: .variable(0.7)
    }
}
```